# why is my css and html not placing my items where i want them

Tags: css

I have just (i.e., today!) started with the CSS grid but it doesnt seem to work. Before that however I notice that every single tutorial about it uses class instead of id. Is this because you have to use classes and not ids? I used class anyway but it still didn't work!
OK... just a simple structure to start with. I want a header, LH column for nav, main area, and RH column for other stuff (css in external stylesheet) but the header text and picture just appear on the LHS rather than 200 pixels in.

```
.container
{
    display:grid | inline-grid;
    grid-template-columns:200px auto 250px;
    grid-template-rows: 300px auto;
}
.navbar
{
    grid-column-start:1;
    grid-column-end:2;
    grid-row-start:2;
    grid-row-end:3;
    
}
.header
{
    grid-column-start:2;
    grid-column-end:4;
    grid-row-start:1;
    grid-row-end:2; 
}
```

and the HTML: (obviously inside the <body> tags!)

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="header"><h1>Astronomy Speakers - Astronomical Societies</h1><img src="headerpic.jpg" alt="astrospe          akers header" style="margin-left:40px" /></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You can't define two display types in the same rule. Pick just one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for `.container`, you cannot have both grid and inline grid.

What I *think* happened here is you copied this code from a website that had `grid | inline grid` displaying as the options for the display property

Comment: Aha! Yes, that's exactly it. Works a treat now - thanks so much for being so perceptive.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between class and Ids is that classes can be used several times on the same page,while Ids can only be used once on the same page. Also I did not see navbar used on your HTML code.

Comment: Mm, yes I knew that, so surely for a page that would typically consist of several differently-styled items, one would use id's rather than classes, which was why I wondered about it. I didn't include 'navbar' purely for reasons of space.